# Failed to load type

Tags: java, jsp, activemq-classic

I'm using Netbeans IDE.

> INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/12/29 23:27:18 | Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation     1.7.0_51 C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:18 | Heap sizes: current=15872k free=12594k max=506816k.
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:18 | JVM args: -Dactivemq.home=./. -Dactivemq.base=./. -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=././conf/broker.ks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=././conf/broker.ts -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dorg.apache.activemq.UseDedicatedTaskRunner=true -DJava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Xmx512m -DJava.library.path=././bin/win32 -Dwrapper.key=nnnVAsNERmehemBP -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.pid=632 -Dwrapper.version=3.2.3 -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10 -Dwrapper.jvmid=1.
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:18 | ACTIVEMQ_HOME:..
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:18 | ACTIVEMQ_BASE:..
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:18 | Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml.
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | INFO CamelNamespaceHandler - camel-osgi.jar not detected in classpath.
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | ERROR: Java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load type: processing.XslProcessor. Reason: Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: processing.XslProcessor; nested exception is Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: processing.XslProcessor.
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | Java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load type: processing.XslProcessor. Reason: Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: processing.XslProcessor; nested exception is Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: processing.XslProcessor.
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask (StartCommand.java:98)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute (AbstractCommand.java:57)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask (ShellCommand.java:129)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute (AbstractCommand.java:57)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main (ShellCommand.java:79)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at Java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass (Main.java:251)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main (Main.java:107)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at Java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run (WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at Java.lang.Thread.run (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load type: processing.XslProcessor. Reason: Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: processing.XslProcessor; nested exception is Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: processing.XslProcessor.
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanQNameHelper.getBeanInfo (XBeanQNameHelper.java:75)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanQNameHelper.coerceNamespaceAwarePropertyValues (XBeanQNameHelper.java:54)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement (XBeanBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:59)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement (BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:389)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement (BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:358)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.processBeanDefinition (XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:174)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement (XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:101)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions (XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:81)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions (DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanXmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions (XBeanXmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:79)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions (ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:111)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions (ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:104)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory (AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory (AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext (XBeanBrokerFactory.java:96)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker (XBeanBrokerFactory.java:52)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker (BrokerFactory.java:71)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker (BrokerFactory.java:54)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.startBroker (StartCommand.java:115)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask (StartCommand.java:74)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 |. 16 more.
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | Caused by: Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: processing.XslProcessor.
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at Java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at Java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at Java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at Java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at Java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at Java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanQNameHelper.loadClass (XBeanQNameHelper.java:107)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanQNameHelper.getBeanInfo (XBeanQNameHelper.java:72)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 |. 42 more.
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | ERROR: Java.lang.Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load type: processing.XslProcessor. Reason: Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: processing.XslProcessor; nested exception is Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: processing.XslProcessor.
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | Java.lang.Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load type: processing.XslProcessor. Reason: Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: processing.XslProcessor; nested exception is Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: processing.XslProcessor.
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask (StartCommand.java:99)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute (AbstractCommand.java:57)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask (ShellCommand.java:129)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute (AbstractCommand.java:57)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main (ShellCommand.java:79)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at Java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass (Main.java:251)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main (Main.java:107)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at Java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run (WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at Java.lang.Thread.run (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load type: processing.XslProcessor. Reason: Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: processing.XslProcessor; nested exception is Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: processing.XslProcessor.
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanQNameHelper.getBeanInfo (XBeanQNameHelper.java:75)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanQNameHelper.coerceNamespaceAwarePropertyValues (XBeanQNameHelper.java:54)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement (XBeanBeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:59)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement (BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:389)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement (BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:358)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.processBeanDefinition (XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:174)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement (XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:101)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions (XBeanBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:81)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions (DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanXmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions (XBeanXmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:79)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions (ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:111)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions (ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:104)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory (AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory (AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext (XBeanBrokerFactory.java:96)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker (XBeanBrokerFactory.java:52)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker (BrokerFactory.java:71)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker (BrokerFactory.java:54)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.startBroker (StartCommand.java:115)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask (StartCommand.java:74)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 |. 16 more.
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | Caused by: Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: processing.XslProcessor.
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at Java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at Java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at Java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (Native Method)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at Java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at Java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at Java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (Unknown Source)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanQNameHelper.loadClass (XBeanQNameHelper.java:107)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 | at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanQNameHelper.getBeanInfo (XBeanQNameHelper.java:72)
>   INFO | jvm 1 | 2015/12/29 23:27:19 |. 42 more.

Activemq.xml:

```
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core
http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd
http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

<!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
     <property name="locations">
        <value>file:${activemq.base}/conf/credentials.properties</value>
     </property>
</bean>

<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/data">

<plugins>
         <authorizationPlugin>
                <map>
                      <authorizationMap>
                            <authorizationEntries>
                                  <authorizationEntry queue=">" read="admins,users" write="admins,users" admin="admins,users"/>
                        <authorizationEntry topic="ActiveMQ.Advisory.>" read="guests,users" write="guests,users" admin="guests,users"/>
                            </authorizationEntries>
                     </authorizationMap>
                </map>
              </authorizationPlugin>
        <simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
            <users>
                <authenticationUser username="test" password="test" groups="users"/>
                <authenticationUser username="system" password="manager" groups="admins,users"/>
            </users>
        </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
</plugins>

    <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
            <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry queue=">" memoryLimit="5mb"/>
                <policyEntry topic=">" memoryLimit="5mb">
                    <dispatchPolicy>
                        <strictOrderDispatchPolicy/>
                    </dispatchPolicy>
                    <subscriptionRecoveryPolicy>
                        <lastImageSubscriptionRecoveryPolicy/>
                    </subscriptionRecoveryPolicy>
                </policyEntry>
            </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>

    <managementContext>
        <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
    </managementContext>

    <networkConnectors>
        <!-- by default just auto discover the other brokers -->
        <networkConnector name="default-nc" uri="multicast://default" userName="system" password="manager"/>
        <networkConnector name="localhost" uri="static://(tcp://127.0.0.1:61616)" userName="system" password="manager"/>
    </networkConnectors>

    <persistenceAdapter>
        <amqPersistenceAdapter syncOnWrite="false" directory="${activemq.base}/data" maxFileLength="20 mb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>

    <sslContext>
        <sslContext keyStore="file:${activemq.base}/conf/broker.ks" keyStorePassword="password" trustStore="file:${activemq.base}/conf/broker.ts" trustStorePassword="password"/>
    </sslContext>

    <systemUsage>
        <systemUsage>
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage limit="20 mb"/>
            </memoryUsage>
            <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="1 gb" name="foo"/>
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="100 mb"/>
            </tempUsage>
        </systemUsage>
    </systemUsage>

    <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616" discoveryUri="multicast://default" />
        <transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61617" />
        <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613" />
        <transportConnector name="xmpp" uri="xmpp://0.0.0.0:61222" />
    </transportConnectors>

</broker>

<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <package>processing</package>

    <route>
        <from uri="activemq:test"/>
        <multicast>
        <to uri="activemq:toStdOut"/>
        <to uri="activemq:toStdOut2"/>
        <to uri="activemq:routeError"/>
        </multicast>
    </route>

<!-- Contr1 inbound route -->
<route>
    <from uri="activemq:contr1In"/>
    <to uri="activemq:contr1InTransform"/>
    <bean ref="contr1InProcessor" method="process"/>
    <multicast>
        <to uri="activemq:oneCIn"/>
    </multicast>
</route>

<!-- Contr1 outbound route -->
<route>
    <from uri="activemq:contr1OutTransform"/>
    <bean ref="contr1OutProcessor" method="process"/>
    <to uri="activemq:contr1Out"/>
</route>

<!-- OneC outbound route -->
<route>
    <from uri="activemq:oneCOut"/>
    <choice>
                <when>
                    <xpath>//contr-id = '1'</xpath>
                    <to uri="activemq:contr1OutTransform"/>
                </when>
        <otherwise>
                    <to uri="activemq:routeError"/>
                </otherwise>
    </choice>
</route>

</camelContext>

<bean id="contr1InProcessor" class="processing.XslProcessor">
<property name="xslName" value="PrepareRequest.xsl"/>
<property name="contrId" value="1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="contr1OutProcessor" class="processing.XslProcessor">
<property name="xslName" value="PrepareResponse.xsl"/>
<property name="contrId" value="1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="errorConsumerBean" class="processing.ErrorConsumer" lazy-init="false">
<property name="destinationDir" value="D:\1c-jms\1c-jms\errors"/>
</bean>

<bean id="testBean" class="processing.Test" lazy-init="false"/>

<!-- configure the camel activemq component to use the current broker -->
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
      <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost?create=false&amp;waitForStart=10000" />
        <property name="userName" value="system"/>
        <property name="password" value="manager"/>
      </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Uncomment to create a command agent to respond to message based admin commands on the ActiveMQ.Agent topic -->
<!--
<commandAgent xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerUrl="vm://localhost" username="${activemq.username}" password="${activemq.password}"/>
-->

<!-- An embedded servlet engine for serving up the Admin console -->
<jetty xmlns="http://mortbay.com/schemas/jetty/1.0">
    <connectors>
        <nioConnector port="8161"/>
    </connectors>

    <handlers>
        <webAppContext contextPath="/admin" resourceBase="${activemq.base}/webapps/admin" logUrlOnStart="true"/>
        <webAppContext contextPath="/camel" resourceBase="${activemq.base}/webapps/camel" logUrlOnStart="true"/>
        <webAppContext contextPath="/demo" resourceBase="${activemq.base}/webapps/demo" logUrlOnStart="true"/>
        <webAppContext contextPath="/fileserver" resourceBase="${activemq.base}/webapps/fileserver" logUrlOnStart="true"/>
    </handlers>
</jetty>
```

Class:

```
public class XslProcessor implements Processor
{

private String xslName = null;
private String contrId = null;

@EndpointInject(uri="activemq:error")
private ProducerTemplate errorProducer = null;

public ProducerTemplate getErrorProducer()
{
    return errorProducer;
}
public void setErrorProducer(ProducerTemplate errorProducer)
{
    this.errorProducer = errorProducer;
}

public static class MyErrorListener implements ErrorListener
{
    private Throwable lastException = null;

    public Throwable getLastException()
    {
        return lastException;
    }
    public void setLastException(Throwable lastException)
    {
        this.lastException = lastException;
    }

    public void error(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException
    {
        lastException = exception;
    }

    public void fatalError(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException
    {
        lastException = exception;
    }

    public void warning(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException
    {
        lastException = exception;
    }
}

public String getXslName()
{
    return xslName;
}
public void setXslName(String xslName)
{
    this.xslName = xslName;
}

public String getContrId()
{
    return contrId;
}
public void setContrId(String contrId)
{
    this.contrId = contrId;
}

public void process(Exchange _exchange) throws Exception
{
    byte[] buf = _exchange.getIn().getBody(byte[].class);
    ByteArrayInputStream xmlStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
    try
    {
        StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(xmlStream);
        InputStream xslStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(xslName);
        MyErrorListener errorListener = new MyErrorListener();
        try
        {
            StreamSource xslSource = new StreamSource(xslStream);

            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setErrorListener(errorListener);

            Transformer t = factory.newTransformer(xslSource);
            ByteArrayOutputStream resultStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            try
            {
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(resultStream);
                t.setParameter("contrId", contrId);
                t.transform(xmlSource, result);
                if (errorListener.lastException != null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Exception in xslt: ",errorListener.lastException);
                }

                resultStream.flush();
                _exchange.getOut().setBody(resultStream.toByteArray(), byte[].class);
            }
            finally
            {
                resultStream.close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            xslStream.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Throwable _t)
    {
        errorProducer.sendBody(buf);
    }
    finally
    {
        xmlStream.close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the first line of `XslProcessor`, and how are you packaging the class file?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch See [screenshot](https://4.downloader.disk.yandex.ru/preview/f8ea630949c3ea7d73cf55c68bf63d6729f042244e2746187f5b744c0da2938e/inf/OiZAszvDseEZ-PNv92GR7T8BXWNfoP0KjCnXEdoWmq4tDLGtICnkMlBLN8ixXVqIauMvZDMU8-r6ZZNClzXFcg%3D%3D?uid=207527256&filename=netbeans.jpg&disposition=inline&hash=&limit=0&content_type=image%2Fjpeg&tknv=v2&size=1280x812)

Comment: @IgChim , try to include the details in your post, not in external websites.